# Rastreador de conteúdo para páginas externas com PHP

Tags: php

Recebi a missão de criar um script que irá capturar o preço, imagem e conteúdo de produtos de alguns sites indicados pelo administrador da aplicação, levando em conta que a estrutura de cada um destes sites seja diferente, e que o script precisaria varrer todas as páginas relacionadas a categoria do produto ou sub páginas de um determinado endereço (ex: /camisas/, /camisas/preto, /camisas/azul). No inicio pensei que poderia fazer isso utilizando DOMXPath + cURL do PHP para buscar áreas relativas a produtos, porém não me parece o jeito correto.

Poderiam me indicar por onde começar, o que utilizar para criar algo assim?

Comment: Parece ser o jeito correto. Melhor seria usar um navegador headless, ou melhor ainda pedir permissão aos sites visitados esperando deles uma API.

Comment: No caso seria com permissão aos sites visitados, porém, não posso contar com a utilização de APIs, então deve mesmo ser um rastreador.

Comment: Nem mesmo algo vindo da framework que eles utilizam? Uma saída em XML? Se eles otimizaram o código para usuários sem javascript use um parser de HTML, se não use um navegador headless.

Comment: Pelo jeito você vai ter que entender a estrutura de cada site e depois fazer as bibliotecas para ler os dados que você precisa.
Com essas limitações vai ser realmente complicado.
Tente procurar por algum *web content miner* e veja se existe algum que você possa usar

Answer (score 3):

Você quer na verdade criar um Web Crawler.

Há uma biblioteca em PHP para criação de Web Crawlers:

http://phpcrawl.cuab.de/

Traduzindo o exemplo do site principal:

```php
<?php 

// Tempo de atuação do crawler 
set_time_limit(10000); 

// Inclusão da classe principal
include("libs/PHPCrawler.class.php"); 

// Extendendo a classe principal e fazendo override no método handleDocumentInfo()
class MyCrawler extends PHPCrawler  
{ 
  function handleDocumentInfo($DocInfo)  
  { 
    // Dectecta quebra de linha na saída ("\n" em modo CLI, "<br>" em outros casos). 
    if (PHP_SAPI == "cli") $lb = "\n"; 
    else $lb = "<br />"; 

    // Imprime URL e Status HTTP
    echo "Page requested: ".$DocInfo->url." (".$DocInfo->http_status_code.")".$lb; 

    // Imprime URL referenciada
    echo "Referer-page: ".$DocInfo->referer_url.$lb; 

    // Imprime se conteúdo do documento foi recebido ou não. 
    if ($DocInfo->received == true) 
      echo "Content received: ".$DocInfo->bytes_received." bytes".$lb; 
    else 
      echo "Content not received".$lb;  

    // O conteúdo da página está em $DocInfo->source

    echo $lb; 

    flush(); 
  }  
} 

// Crie uma instância da sua classe, defina o comportamento do crawler
// e inicie o processo.

$crawler = new MyCrawler(); 

// URL para realizar o crawling
$crawler->setURL("www.php.net"); 

// Faz o crawl apenas de documentos content-type "text/html" 
$crawler->addContentTypeReceiveRule("#text/html#"); 

// Ignorar imagens
$crawler->addURLFilterRule("#\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$# i"); 

// Armazenar cookies
$crawler->enableCookieHandling(true); 

// Baixar apenas 1 megabyte do site (não precisa baixar tudo)
$crawler->setTrafficLimit(1000 * 1024); 

// Se tudo está ok, só chamar o método go()
$crawler->go(); 

// Para imprimir um relatório do processo, use o método abaixo
$report = $crawler->getProcessReport(); 

if (PHP_SAPI == "cli") $lb = "\n"; 
else $lb = "<br />"; 

echo "Sumário:".$lb; 
echo "Links seguidos: ".$report->links_followed.$lb; 
echo "Documentss recebidos: ".$report->files_received.$lb; 
echo "Bytes recebidos: ".$report->bytes_received." bytes".$lb; 
echo "Tempo de execução: ".$report->process_runtime." sec".$lb;  
?>
```

Comment: Cigano Morrison Mendez, eu consigo pegar imagens com essa lib ?

Comment: Consegue. Esse crawler consegue baixar imagens. Só no exemplo que coloquei que ele ignora, pro caso de um crawler que lida apenas com texto.