# Sistema de comentários com vídeo

Tags: php

Ao fazer um comentário no Facebook, por exemplo, e adicionar um link para o vídeo do youtube, vimeo e outros, repare que automaticamente é feito o embed do video.

O mesmo se passa quando inserimos um link para uma imagem ou para um site.

Reparem que no comentário fica uma imagem do site ou do vídeo.

Como é feito esse tipo de comentário utilizando o php?

Comment: Precisa ser em PHP ou pode ser em JavaScript?

Comment: @Kazzkiq tem que ser gravado na base de dados, penso que só com Javascript não vai dar, é necessário o PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenho um [plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/post-from-og/) de WordPress que faz algo parecido usando as tags de [Open Graph <sup>(en)</sup>](http://ogp.me/) inseridas em muitas páginas web de hoje em dia.

Exemplo de [um vídeo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aZMbTFNp4wI) no YouTube:

```
<meta property="og:site_name" content="YouTube">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aZMbTFNp4wI">
<meta property="og:title" content="No Woman, No Drive">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/aZMbTFNp4wI/maxresdefault.jpg">
<meta property="og:description" content="Download directly from us: http://ldr.fm/tX6XP Download from iTunes: https://itun.es/i6F668z Follow: Hisham Fageeh: http://Twitter.com/HishamFageeh Fahad Alb...">
<meta property="og:type" content="video">
<meta property="og:video" content="http://www.youtube.com/v/aZMbTFNp4wI?version=3&amp;autohide=1">
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash">
<meta property="og:video:width" content="1920">
<meta property="og:video:height" content="1080">
```

Além do OG, existem também os [Twitter Cards e outras Meta Data sociais <sup>(en)</sup>](https://yoast.com/twitter-cards/):

```
<meta name="twitter:url" content="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aZMbTFNp4wI">
<meta property="al:android:url" content="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aZMbTFNp4wI">
<meta property="al:ios:app_name" content="YouTube">
```

O processo no plugin é:

- `<input>` de texto onde o usuário cola o link,
- dispara-se uma requisição AJAX a uma função PHP,
- o PHP faz a leitura da URL e analisa o conteúdo extraindo as informações OG e Twitter, de onde se extrai: título, descrição, imagem representativa,
- devolve-se as informações em formato JSON ao JavaScript e renderiza-se o conteúdo recebido usando jQuery.

O seguinte código é parte da função que o AJAX invoca e que processa os resultados da consulta à URL. O WordPress faz o `REQUEST HTTP` usando a extensão Curl ou o Streams do PHP (depende do caso). Mas enfim, só preciso chamar a função `wp_remote_get`, ela me devolve o resultado e faço o processamento do `$response['body`]`:

```
if ( $data = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ) )
{
    $rmetas = array(); // Array for JSON
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true); 

    $doc = new DomDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($data);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

    $query = '//*/meta[starts-with(@property, \'og:\')]';
    $ogs = $xpath->query( $query );
    foreach ( $ogs as $meta ) 
    {
        $property = $meta->getAttribute('property');
        $content = $meta->getAttribute('content');
        $rmetas[$property] = $content;
    }

    if( empty( $rmetas ) )
        wp_send_json_error( array( 'error' => __( 'No OG data in the page.' ) ) );

    /* Meta Data for the post */
    if( $autor = $this->xpath_query( $xpath, 'meta', 'name', 'author', 'content' ) )
        $rmetas['author'] = $autor; 
    if( $date = $this->xpath_query( $xpath, 'meta', 'name', 'dc.date', 'content' ) )
        $rmetas['date'] = $date;    
    if( $url = $this->xpath_query( $xpath, 'link', 'rel', 'shorturl', 'href' ) )
        $rmetas['shorturl'] = $url; 
    if( $aurl = $this->xpath_query( $xpath, 'meta', 'property', "article:author", 'content' ) )
        $rmetas['authorurl'] = $aurl;   

    $twits = $xpath->query('//*/meta[starts-with(@property, \'twitter:\')]');
    foreach ( $twits as $meta ) 
    {
        $property = $meta->getAttribute('property');
        $content = $meta->getAttribute('value');
        if( 'twitter:site' == $property )
            $rmetas['twitter'] = $content;  
    }

    wp_send_json_success( $rmetas ); // Esta função inclui um die(); o erro abaixo não roda
}

wp_send_json_error( array( 'error' => __( 'Undefined error.' ) ) );
```

As *queries* do DOMXpath fiz com ajuda do Stack Overflow, simplesmente [pesquisando dentro esta busca avançada](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%2bDOMDocument%20%2bDOMXPath%20is:answer) até achar algo adequado.

Se as meta informações não estiverem presentes na página, poderia-se fazer um [*scrape*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scrape?sort=frequent&pageSize=50) tradicional, mas nunca cheguei a esse ponto. Porém vejo coisas interessantes aqui (----->) na coluna *Relacionados*:

- [Rastreador de conteúdo para páginas externas com PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8330/rastreador-de-conteudo-para-paginas-externas-com-php?rq=1)
- [Como listar mais de 50 vídeos do Youtube utilizando cURL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11764/como-listar-mais-de-50-videos-do-youtube-utilizando-curl?rq=1)

Comment: Agrada-me a resposta :). Entretanto o que impede o utilizador de colocar um link para um site malicioso? Se ele postar um link para um site malicioso, o meu site pode ser indexado pelo google como um possível site malicioso também, pelo facto de conter links para sites maliciosos?

Comment: Mas isso é um problema *geral* do sistema de comentários, não? Independente de puxar imagens ou não, a moderação de spam e de abusos é outro problema... E como é seu sistema de comentários? No FB, se não me engano, tem um `input` exclusivo pra URL que se quer postar junto com o comentário, não é isso?

Comment: No facebook se vc colocar o url no campo para o comentário, ele identifica se é uma imagem, video, artigo, etc... e coloca o thumb no post. Nunca tentei inserir um link malicioso para ver o que acontecia. :)

Answer (score 2):

Aqui vou delinear de forma simplificada como imagino a abordagem utilizada.

Este tipo de controle utiliza uma combinação de diferentes tecnologias, ambas do lado do cliente e do servidor.

No caso dos vídeos, é possível que o processo seja feito apenas com tecnologia de front-end.

Ao colar um link, o navegador realiza um evento de "colagem". Neste evento um código JavaScript pode ler o conteúdo deste texto e procurar "youtube.com","vimeo.com", e, uma vez que o link seja válido, criar um player embedded.

No caso das imagens, repare que o FB oferece uma lista das imagens do site. De forma semelhante aos vídeos, quando um usuário cola um texto, um código JavaScript procura "http://..." e " www." no texto  colado. Se for um link válido, o JS dispara um pedido para o servidor, para que ele faça um crawl no link e retorne: o título (procurando tags `<h2>`, `<h3>` ou classes como `.title`, `#title`, etc.), a introdução (procurando por tags `<p>`) e as imagens da página (procurando por tags `<img>`).

Repare que esta requisição não é instantânea, demora alguns segundos até que o servidor retorne todas as informações - e se a página estiver mal estruturada, nem sempre será possível identificar o título e a introdução).

Mais informações:
[Detectar texto colado](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211505/detect-pasted-text-with-ctrlv-or-right-click-paste)
[Realizar crawl em páginas web com PHP](http://desenvolvimentoparaweb.com/php/como-pegar-parte-do-conteudo-dados-de-outro-site-com-php/)